# Stability of the fractional derivative of a stable signal

Tags: derivatives, fractional-calculus, stability-theory

Is fractional derivative of a continuous stable signal,stable? The fractional derivative is between 0 and 1.

Comment: What you mean by *stable*?

Comment: stable in the sense of Lyapunov.